# Free base autosuggest

Tags: freebase

I am using the free base autosuggest 
i use this code ,,,

> $("#example1")   .suggest()
>   .bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
>        });

some users details also getting in that suggest how to filter  that....

Answer (score 1):

The [Freebase Suggest documentation](http://www.freebase.com/docs/suggest) shows lots of examples of how to filter the results.

For example, you can constrain the autocomplete to only show companies and organizations like this:

```
$("#example4")
.suggest({
  "type": ["/business/company", "/organization/organization"],
  "type_strict": "any"
}).bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {});
```

What are you trying to build with Freebase suggest? What results would you like it to display?